# POST in RESTful web service

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

am trying to learn the basic CURD operations to do in RESTful web service using Jersy or Restlet.

Could anyone provide me with some examples on how to POST a word/message from ONE web application to another web application (i.e) to POST a message from the first application and then to implement GET in the second application to receive it.

Thanks,

Comment: You should learn first REST and the meaning of the HTTP Methods. Use POST  to create a resource on the web service and GET to get a resource representation.

Answer (score 0):

may it's useful for you its codeigniter post web service demo

```
public function add_category() {
    ###############  post parameter #######

    $user_id = $this->is_require($_POST, 'user_id');
    $user_token = $this->is_require($_POST, 'user_token');
    $cat_name = $this->is_require($_POST, 'cat_name');
    $parent_id = $this->is_require($_POST, 'parent_id');
    $this->Is_authorised($user_id, $user_token, 1);
    #######################################
    $q = "select * from tbl_category where cat_name='$cat_name' and parent_id ='$parent_id' limit 1";
    $c_exits = $this->basic->select_custom($q);
    if (!empty($c_exits)) {
        $this->msg = "category already exist";
        $this->_sendResponse(2);
    }

    $inn = array(
        'cat_name' => $cat_name,
        'parent_id' => $parent_id,
    );

    $temp = $this->basic->insert_entry("tbl_category", $inn, TRUE);
    if ($temp['stat'] == 1) {
        $this->result['cat_id'] = $temp['last_id'];
    } else {
        $this->_sendResponse(0);
    }
    $this->_sendResponse(1);
}
```